# Como hacer que un Console.ReadLine() pueda leer un mismo string o numero a la vez?

Tags: c#

Ya he avanzado bastante con mi código sobre el parquímetro, conseguí ahora que pueda obtener tantos minutos según las monedas insertadas, pero ahora, quiero hacer una función que me permita aceptar dichos minutos sumados, sin tener que llegar al limite.

Me explico, imaginen que solo quiero 10 minutos de tiempo extra... meto las monedas, confirmo, y luego me dará el ticket. Quiero que la variable para aceptar sea una "x", pero cuando lo hago, me esta haciendo un `console.Readline()` dos veces, uno para leer el monto ingresado, y otro para leer el `string`, y solo quiero que este se repita una sola vez, aquí les asigno el código:

```
    public static void VerPaquimetro()
    {
        double[] moedas = { 0.10, 0.20, 0.50, 1, 2 };
        double[] minutos = { 4, 8, 20, 40, 78 };

        
        double ReceverMoeda;
        double saldo = 0;
        double tempo = 0;
        double tempoMax = 45;




        Helpers.HelperMoedas();
        
        for (int i = 0; tempo <= tempoMax - 1 || Console.ReadLine() == "x" || saldo <= 1.15; i++)
        {


            ReceverMoeda = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            
            
            if (ReceverMoeda == 0)
            {
                HelperReset();
            } 
            

            if (ReceverMoeda == moedas[0])
            {
                saldo += moedas[0];
                tempo += minutos[0];
                HelperParquimetro(tempo, saldo);

                if (Console.ReadLine() == "x")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Aceitado o dinheiro");
                    break;
                }

               

            }
            else if (ReceverMoeda == moedas[1])
            {
                saldo += moedas[1];
                tempo += minutos[1];
                HelperParquimetro(tempo, saldo);

                if (Console.ReadLine() == "x")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Aceitado o dinheiro");
                    break;
                }

              

            }
            else if (ReceverMoeda == moedas[2])
            {
                saldo += moedas[2];
                tempo += minutos[2];
                HelperParquimetro(tempo, saldo);

                if (Console.ReadLine() == "x")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Aceitado o dinheiro");
                    break;
                }


          
            }
            else if (ReceverMoeda == moedas[3])
            {
                saldo += moedas[3];
                tempo += minutos[3];
                HelperParquimetro(tempo, saldo);

                if (Console.ReadLine() == "x")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Aceitado o dinheiro");
                    break;
                }
    
            }
            else if (ReceverMoeda == moedas[4])
            {
                saldo += moedas[4];
                tempo += minutos[4];
                HelperParquimetro(tempo, saldo);
                if (Console.ReadLine() == "x")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Aceitado o dinheiro");

                    break;
                }


            }
            



        }
        Console.WriteLine("Retire as suas moedas {0:N2}", saldo - 1.15);


    }

    public static void HelperParquimetro(double tempo, double saldo)
    {
        DateTime tempoAtual = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime tempoAtual1 = tempoAtual.AddMinutes(tempo);

        Console.WriteLine("Saldo Atual: {0:N2}", saldo);
        Console.WriteLine(tempoAtual1.ToShortTimeString());

    }

    public static void HelperReset()
    {
        
            Console.WriteLine("Retira a tuas moedas ...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("Reset ...");
            Thread.Sleep(250);
            Console.Clear();
            VerPaquimetro();
        


    }
```

Comment: hay tantos readline, que ni idea cual puede ser el problema... porque tantos??? cual es la idea?? porque nunca te quedas con el valor ingresado???

Comment: si decis que sale dos veces, hiciste un debug linea a linea a ver que linea repite ese readline???